# Resolving a Multi index in a Dataframe for better clarity

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, indexing

So,  I split the sentences in a row into single words, and thus, the rows of my dataframe got lengthened. however, I am not satisfied with the new indexes.

```
0  0                I
   1              don
   2                '
   3                t
   4            think
   5              any
```

What i would like, would be to make the index on the left swap places with the next one, and then,
pass a argument like (Sentence: 'X'), where X would denote the original index of the sentence which the word belonged to.

```
 0      Sentence:0          I
 1      Sentence:0          don
 2      Sentence:0          '
 3      Sentence:0          t
 4      Sentence:0          think
 5                          any
```

However,

```
df['index1'] = df.index
```

only lets me access the second index, and so i cannot get the indexes to swap positions.

How might I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand right that you want to swap the levels of your Multiindex?

Maybe this helps you:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html

Edit: Answering the second part of your question:

```
df.rename(lambda x: "Sentence "+str(x), level=1)
```

does the renaming you asked for